# Delphi XE6 won't use DCC32, always calls DCC64 Regardless of Platform

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I think I have broken my Delphi DXE6?  I'm trying to install Orpheus 4.08 so I can open some old forms with Orpheus design-time components.

It won't build, and I notice that it's creating Win64 folders where it should be creating Win32.  ex:
\Orpheus\packages\Delphi XE6\Win64\Release

I have the Target Platform set to 32-bit Windows. I even deleted the 64-bit one, and it keeps creating that folder. Further inspection shows that regardless of which platform I'm targeting, it uses DCC64.exe for the compiler. This can't be right, can it?  Have I broken Delphi somehow, or am I doing something wrong?

So I thought I was going crazy, and created a new VCL app from scratch, configured 32-bit, Debug.  Sure enough, it is sent to: C:\Users\cthornto\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Win64\Debug

What is going on here?

Comment: SysInternals Process Explorer reports that my sample VCL app is a 64-bit image, confirming my suspicion.

Comment: I'd reinstall from scratch to be on safe side

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I usually hate that, but in this particular situation, very few of my add-on controls are actually working, so there isn't much to loose here.

Comment: You'll have no confidence unless you reinstall

Comment: yeah, I was looking for an easy answer, like some switch I'd forgotten about. Like "always compile 64-bit, no matter what"

Comment: What I really need to do, is get a new PC and REALLY start over...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, it happened because some other program created a System Environment Variable named Platform with the value "Win64" and Delphi uses a variable with the same name during compilation.

To solve it, I've overridden the system variable with and empty one in Tools > Options > Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

David was right, a full uninstall/re-install did the trick.